# Give a user permission to one folder

Tags: ssh, group, sftp

I have set up my machine so that my group "sftponly" can access the users home folder. But right now, the users in the group don't have permission to other folders, but they have permission to see them.

How can I change this so that the users in the group only can see their home folder?

My OS is Ubuntu, this is in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match Group sftponly
    ChrootDirectory %h
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Right now, it looks like this when a user connects with SFTP:

[image: What it is now]
Right now they can see all folders, but I only want them to be in the folder they start in, so they can't go up in the folders and see the other users' home folders.

Comment: Can you please provide the question with an example (current & expected  behaviour)  ?

Comment: @Neuron You can see it the edit.

Comment: If you want to have user who sees only his folder, you need to chroot his sftp session.

Comment: @Jakuje I've already chroot it like this:

http://pastebin.com/hH08EhKy

Comment: Reloaded the SSH server? Also, why don't you use `ChrootDirectory %h` so each user is chrooted in its own home directory?

Comment: You can try this, but it will probably not work: because as you can see in sshd_config(5): 
`All components of the pathname must be root-owned directories that are not writable by any other user or group.`

Comment: @sebix i've tried that but i used it for a test to the user "strengthhost", and yes i did restart the ssh server. Some changes happend.

When i'm logged on the user and try to access a folder inside a other users folder i can't access it. If i remove the ChrootDirectory i can access all files and folders.
So something happens.

Comment: Could just be a typo...?  You refer to group `sftponly` in `sshd_config`, but, at the beginning of your question, you specify `ftponly` as the group to which your users belong.

Comment: I changed the group to `sftponly`
I found out that i forgot to add the user to the group... sry...
But know my user can't even connect to the sftp..
FileZilla gives me this: `Server unexpectedly closed network connection`

Comment: Same symptom solved by this [answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/135212/sftp-chroot-access-via-ssh).  Basically what @Jakuje pointed out above regarding directory ownership/permissions.

Comment: So now i edited the ChrootDirectory to be %h. I set the owner of the users directory as owner. And i gave the folder 755 perms. But it seems like it still now working...

Comment: I tried to remove the path in the `sshd_config` file, and now the user can't even go to their own home folder, even they own the folder and the folder have 755 perms.

Comment: The home directories `/home/strengthhost` and so on have to be owned by root.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using VSFTPD if you're not doing so already, and un-comment chroot_local_user=YES in vsftpd.conf.